# Swift: Getting a Button to work

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, viewdidload

I created two buttons in my `viewDidLoad()` function:

```
    buttonZ.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 100, 50)
    buttonZ.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    buttonZ.setTitle("Zurück", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonZ.addTarget(self, action: "buttonZAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(buttonZ)

    buttonV.frame = CGRectMake(screenBreite - 100, 20, 100, 50)
    buttonV.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    buttonV.setTitle("Vorwärts", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonV.addTarget(self, action: "buttonVAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(buttonV)
```

Outside the `viewDidLoad()` I implemented the two functions `buttonZAction()`and `buttonVAction()`

```
    func buttonZAction(){
    if(level - 1 >= 1){
        level = level - 1
        spielfeldChooser()
    }
}

func buttonVAction(){
    if(level + 1 <= maxLevel){
        level = level + 1
        spielfeldChooser()
    }
}
```

The problem appears when I am hitting on of these buttons. An exception appears somewhere, which I do not catch (I just included the main part of the error).

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Pushy_2_0.ViewController buttonVAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15db5410'

I hope You can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `"buttonZAction:"` it means that your selector should receive a parameter. If you don't pass them change these lines:

```
buttonZ.addTarget(self, action: "buttonZAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
buttonV.addTarget(self, action: "buttonVAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

To:

```
buttonZ.addTarget(self, action: "buttonZAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
buttonV.addTarget(self, action: "buttonVAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector has a argument. but you did not declare this argument in function **buttonZAction**
like this

```
func buttonZAction(sender: UIButton!){
    if(level - 1 >= 1){
        level = level - 1
        spielfeldChooser()
    }
}

func buttonVAction(sender: UIButton!){
if(level + 1 <= maxLevel){
    level = level + 1
    spielfeldChooser()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added ":" in the end of the String denoting the name of the method of action, this latter takes no input parameter. to not mistake, it would be better to use the Selector class like this:

```
buttonV.addTarget (self, Action: Selector (buttonVAction ()), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```